# PHP print table in the SQL using select statement

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

In the program, I want to create table to print out the date in (Y/M/D) format, volume, pending and sent. However, it show nothing after execution. It can be executed using phpmyadmin in the SQL. However, I do not know whether we can use two SQL statements to find out two different condition. I need your help.

```
$start = date('2013-12-12');
$today = date("Y/m/d");
echo "Today's date: " .$today;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(semail) AS av FROM table WHERE `thedate`>='2013-12-12' GROUP BY `thedate` ")or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("No rows returned by query"); 
$totalofemail = $row['av'];
$sent = mysql_query("SELECT count(semail) AS av FROM table WHERE `sflag`='1' AND `thedate`>='2013-12-12' GROUP BY `thedate`")or die(mysql_error());  
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sent) or die("No rows returned by query");  
$sentemail = $result['av'];
$pending = $totalofemail - $sentemail;

echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Daily volume</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
      </tr>";

if($i=0; $i<($today-$start); $i++)
{
   echo "<tr>\n";
   echo "<td>" . $row['thedate'] . "</td>\n";
   echo "<td>" . $totalofemail . "</td>\n";
   echo "<td>" . $sentemail . "</td>\n";
   echo "<td>" . $pending . "</td>\n";
   echo "\n</tr>\n";
   echo "</table>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason for the error is `if($i=0; $i< ($today-$start); $i++)`

But in your code, there is no need of using `for` loop

try using,

```
for($i=0; $i< ($today-$start); $i++)
```

instead of

```
if($i=0; $i< ($today-$start); $i++)
```

Code: Removed loop condition. since there is no neccessity for the loop.

```
$start = date('2013-12-12');
$today = date("Y/m/d");
echo "Today's date: " .$today;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(semail) AS av FROM mycard WHERE `thedate`>='2013-12-12' GROUP BY `thedate` ")or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("No rows returned by query"); 
$totalofemail = $row['av'];


$sent = mysql_query("SELECT count(semail) AS av FROM mycard WHERE `sflag`='1' AND `thedate`>='2013-12-12' GROUP BY `thedate`")or die(mysql_error());  
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sent) or die("No rows returned by query");  
$sentemail = $result['av'];


$pending = $totalofemail - $sentemail;

echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Daily volume</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
      </tr>";

      echo "<tr>\n";
      echo "<td>" . $row['thedate'] . "</td>\n";
      echo "<td>" . $totalofemail . "</td>\n";
      echo "<td>" . $sentemail . "</td>\n";
      echo "<td>" . $pending . "</td>\n";
      echo "\n</tr>\n";


   echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Sorry, is 'for'loop not 'if'. Yet,after executing the table would not shown that a statement 'No rows returned by query' is shown

Comment: `FROM yourtablename` what is your table name? replace `yourtablename`

Comment: yourtablename = mycard

Comment: Then replace `table` by `mycard` in your sql query, I have updated my answer aswell.

Comment: @user876345. Is it not better to make a complete string. (by concatenation) and echo to the browser only once

Answer (score 1):

What did you want to do? A new perspective?

```
    if($i=0; $i<($today-$start); $i++)
```

Should not it be `for`?

```
for($i=0; $i<($today-$start); $i++)
```

Another "boring" part is about using mysql_* functions. As we all know they are deprecated. Use [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Sorry, it is 'for'loop not 'if'. Yet,after executing the table would not shown that a statement 'No rows returned by query' is shown